# Subversion hide repository path

Tags: svn

How can I configure the subversion server to hide the full repository path from the outside world?

For example, the repository lives under `/home/svn/foobar/` ... I want to access it via ssh as `svn+ssh://user@domain.com/foobar`.

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/100029/subversion-hide-repository-path on ServerFault

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading carefully through the official SVN documentation I have found that when accessing subversion over svn+ssh -- then a separate svnserve process is spawned for every connection. Thus the trick is to

1. Rename `svnserve` to `svnserve.bin`
2. Create a file called `svnserve`
3. Add the following to its contents

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   exec /usr/bin/svnserve.bin -r /home/svn "$@"
   ```

Thus the wrapper will be called everytime a server instance is needed. It will in turn init the server with a new root path.

Piece of cake!

Comment: Another option that doesn't require renaming the binary is to put the svnserve shell script in /usr/local/bin, which (on my box) is earlier in the PATH list.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `--root` option:

```
svnserve --root /home/svn
```

Answer (score 1):

A blog post today went into some great detail about how to setup SSH access to SVN on a server.

http://blog.tampakrap.gr/subversion-setup-and-gorg/#utm_source=feed&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=feed

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTTP(S) protocol instead of SSH. And then, configure Apache with any virtual directory you like.